# Undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT

Tags: php, webdriver, geckodriver

I found a tutorial on youtube about the selenium webdriver in windows using php. I already setup the xampp, installed some dependencies, and others like the jar files and geckodriver. And when I execute the php code. I got this error.

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\phpwebdriver\WebElement.php on line 28
```

Here is my php code:

```php
<?php
/*
Copyright 2011 3e software house & interactive agency

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/


require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");                            
$webdriver->get("http://google.com");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
if ($element) {
    $element->sendKeys(array("hello" ) );
    $element->submit();
}

?>
```

Please somebody help, I've been working for this error for 2days. I don't know what to do. Thanks in advance, really appreciate it if somebody has an answer.

Comment: is this the file: WebElement.php ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but I solve this error by debugging the code.

Go to the inside phpwebdriver folder and find the file webElement.php.
In-line number 28 you will get the code:-

```
parent::__construct($root . "/element/" . $element->ELEMENT);
```

Replace this line to:-

```
foreach ($element as $ele){
parent::__construct($root . "/element/" . $ele);
    }
```

And run the run your test file again. The error will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [WebDriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) it should be ok.

I think you can not use require_once = `phpwebdriver/WebDriver` because it should be replaced by `vendor/autoload.php` like in [this original example](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/master/example.php).

Also I suggest use this.